# TreeSet custom comparator doesn't work with equal objects

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I've got a problem with TreeSet comparator implementation. I've got a simple game where animals walk on the board, every turn they make one movement, if they die for some reason they're marked as "dead", placed into a "DeadOrganisms" list and later removed from treeset "queue" in this piece of code (I cant remove them instantly because I'm iterating over the treeset):

```
for(Organism org : DeadOrganisms){
    queue.remove(org);
}
```

The problem is that some of them aren't getting remove at all even thought at the end of every turn they're placed back in DeadOrganisms list because of being marked as "dead". Being sure that .remove is called every turn on the dead organism I'm pretty sure that the problem lies in Comparator class:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Organism> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Organism o1, Organism o2) {
        if (o1.getName().equals(o2.getName())) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (o1.getInitiative() > o2.getInitiative()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o1.getInitiative() == o2.getInitiative()) {
            if (o1.getAge() > o2.getAge()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

The comparator is supposed to check if the name of o1 (unique for each character on board) is equal to the name of o2 and the rest of code is for sorting the treeset by character's initiative or age if the initiative is equal.
Piece of the code for Organism abstract class that all the characters derive from:

```
public abstract class Organism {
    protected int lastxpos;
    protected int lastypos;
    private final World myworld;
    private int strength;
    private int initiative;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private int age;
    private String name;
    Color color;
    private boolean isdead;
    public Organism(World world, String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.color = Color.RED;
        this.strength = 0;
        this.initiative = 0;
        this.xPos = 0;
        this.yPos = 0;
        this.age = 0;
        this.isdead = false;
        this.myworld = world;
    }
```

I know that I'm either doing something wrong or misunderstanding how TreeSets work (or both) but I can't understand what. I also know that .remove

> removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))

So in my understanding that's the role of

```
if (o1.getName().equals(o2.getName())) {
    return 0;
}
```

in my Comparator class but maybe I'm misunderstanding something.
  I would greatly appreciate any help with that.

@EDIT
I don't know if it matters but so far I'm testing it on one type of animal, with the same age and initative so the only difference between all the animals is their name.

**@EDIT2**
I've also noticed that if the organism to removed is first in the treeset "queue" then, in the compare method, after calling queue.remove(org), the "org" is never compared to 1st object in treeset (aka. itself) only to second, third etc.

**@EDIT3**
For user NPE in the comments:
Queue declaration:

```
public class World extends JPanel{
    *_declarations of some variables_*
    private final TreeSet<Organism> queue;
```

Queue initialization:

```
public World(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        this.queue = new TreeSet<>(new MyComparator());
        *_ommitting rest of constructor code_*
    }
```

DeadOrganisms declaration and initalization:

```
    public void EndTurn(){
        List<Organism> DeadOrganisms = new ArrayList<>();
        *_omitting rest of the EndTurn code_*
     }
```

Comment: Please show us the code that declares and initializes `queue` and `DeadOrganisms`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaDoc of `java.util.Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.

...which sounds suspiciously much like what you're experiencing. So let's look at the [JavaDoc of `java.util.Collection#remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove-java.lang.Object-):

> Removes the specified element from this set if it is present (optional operation). More formally, removes an element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`, if this set contains such an element.

So the `Comparator` doesn't even come into play here. Therefore, the solution is to implement both the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 97 * hash + this.initiative;
    hash = 97 * hash + this.age;
    hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Organism other = (Organism) obj;
    if (this.initiative != other.initiative) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.age != other.age) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note: both method were automatically generated by Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for help, unfortunately the problem was something else. In the comparator you can see that if the initiative is equal and the Organism1 age IS NOT bigger than Organism2 age I would just place Organism1 after Organism2. Now lets say that my objects in treeset are A,B,C,D...,X,Y,Z, their initiative and age are the same. When I add them to my treeset the comparator always returns 1 because the initiative and age are the same, meaning that the order of treeset would always be insertion order. Now, when I wanted to remove the H object, the .remove method would enter the A,B,C,D,...,X,Y,Z treeset, it would start at, for example, F (I don't know if it chooses it randomly or it is some algorithm) and would call comparator with arguments F and H then comparator would return 1 as it always does in this case. The .remove method would then "jump" from F, to, for example, K, completely skipping H, it would compare K and H, the compare would, again, return 1, telling .remove method that H is *possibly* located further into treeset, when in reality the .remove already skipped my H object. That lead to .remove randomly not removing object because it would skip over it in its algorithm. All I needed to do was to add static counter to my organisms. Now the comparator knows that it's looking for wolf with counter value of 3, so if it jumps over it and finds wolf with counter value of 6 it knows that it needs to go back.

TL;DR:

*(TIL: the algorithm of treeset doesn't move from one node to its "neighbour" but rather "jumps" over big sections (they're getting smaller the closer we're getting to our value), meaning that if we're looking for 50 in our set {1,2....100} it would (for example) jump to 20, then to 80, then to 40, then to 55 etc.)*

.remove would jump over my object in treeset because of bad comparator "if" statements.